# How do you get styling props to work on specific elements in VueJs

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I am creating a button and it needs to have multiple states (hover, focused, pressed and disabled).

I also need my default button to have a default size (large) and a smaller size (small). I am trying to get the different attributes passed onto my button via vue props but none of them are working.

At the moment I am just trying  to get some basic size attributes on my button (get the height and width) but they are working and I am not sure why as I am getting no errors.

Below is the button in the `<template>`:

```
<button
      class="primaryButton"
      :class="[
        size + 'large',
        type + 'primary',

        {
          'default-state': !isActive,
          hover: isActive && isHovered,
          focused: isActive && isFocused,
          pressed: isActive && isPressed,
          disabled: isDisabled
        }
      ]"
      @mouseenter="isHovered = true"
      @mouseleave="isHovered = false"
      @focus="isFocused = true"
      @mousedown="isPressed = true"
      @mouseup="isPressed = false"
      @click="handleClick"
      :disabled="isDisabled"
    >
      <slot />
</button>
```

Below is the `<script>`:

```
export default {
  props: {
    size: {
      default: 'large',
      small: 'small'
      //default size
    },
    type: {
      default: 'default',
      focused: 'focused',
      pressed: 'pressed',
      disAbled: 'disAbled'
      //default type
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: true,
      isHovered: false,
      isFocused: false,
      isPressed: false,
      isDisabled: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      if (!this.isDisabled) {
        this.buttonClick
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the `<style>`:

```
.primaryButton {
  background-color: #a5042a;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;

}
.primaryButton:hover {
  background-color: #ed063d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.large-size {
  min-height: 45px;
  min-width: 130px;
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are the classes on the element in the DOM at all? Are the not what you expect? You have `.large-size` in the CSS but you appear to be constructing `largelarge` in the component. Also, please include how your are using this component.

Comment: 'Not working' means that the styling attributes i am aiming to apply to my button are not applying. 

in the file that I am calling the button i am calling like so, 

 <MainButton size="large" type="primary">Default Primary</MainButton>

Comment: Well, that's because of the issue I pointed out: you are constructing the class names incorrectly. I put it in a [Vue playground](https://dub.sh/B6Q3a2w) and that's what I see.

Comment: Instead of `size + 'large'`, you should use `size + '-size'`, and so on. Although I would flip the order and use `.size-large` and co.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) in Vue. You can have a component `BaseButton.vue` to which you will pass props or [fallthrough attributes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html) in order for the button to have different styles. Here is a [small demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) on Vue playground. Here is an example of `BaseButton.vue`

```html
<template>
  <button class="default">
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<style scoped>
.default {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.default:hover {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.large {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.large:hover {
    /* specific hover styles */
}

.small {
    width: 75px;
    height: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have gone through the example and I am sure I am doing that or am I missing something obvious ? 
I have passed the props correctly and called then on the button component in the file where I am using the button but still nothing.

Comment: I got it working in the end. Thank you for the input.